# How to prove there exists a function $h : A → B$ such that $g ◦ h = f$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{4, 5, 6\}, C = \{7, 8, 9, 10\}$.

Define the functions $f : A → C$ and   $g : B → C$ by $f(1) = 7$, $f(2) = 9$, $f(3) = 7$, $g(4) = 10$, $g(5) = 7$, $g(6) = 9$.

I'm approaching this by proving the domains and codomains equal for the functions $g o k$ and f but I'm never sure whether my proof is actually sound.

$f(1) = 7 = g(h(1))$. There exists a $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = 7$, which is 5, so $h(1) = 5$.

I repeated this for the rest of the elements in set $A$. In my eyes, I think that I showed each element in set $A$ maps to the same output for both functions but I'm not sure if this is right or if this alone is even sufficient to prove the function $h$ such that $g ◦ h = f$ exists.

I appreciate any criticism and help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the process you are supposed to go through.  You can think of it as a game of "connect the dots."  If it seems too easy or too trivial, that's because it is and it is just being asked of you here to make sure you are paying attention and understand the words being used.

Comment: Since the sets in question are finite, it may help to draw a diagram and draw arrows. The goal is to find for each $a \in A$ a $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = g(b)$, in which case you can define $h(a) = b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, look where $f$ sends 1, 2 and 3. Since $f(1)=7=f(3)$, we need to have $h(1)$ and $h(3)$ be such $b\in B$ that $g(b)=7$. Such a $b$ exists, namely $b=5$. Then we have $f(2)=9$, so $h(2)$ must be such that $g$ sends it to $9$. This gives us $h(2)=6$. Combining these, we have a function $h\colon\{1, 2, 3\}\to\{4, 5, 6\}$ given by $h(1)=7, h(2)=9, h(3)=7$.

Comment: Yes makes sense, do you think saying h:{1,2,3}→{4,5,6} is necessary to show it's a function? Or is proving the domains and codomains are defined and equal each other enough? Thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: You're welcome! :) The image is just {5, 6}, so the codomain of h could be any set containing those two. Specifying it to be {4, 5, 6} lets us compose it with g whereas {5, 6} or {5, 6, 11} etc. wouldn't! But the essential part is just to find an element for each of the 1, 2 and 3 to get a function h mapping into {4, 5, 6}.